# How to fix python overwriting file in append mode?

Tags: python

I'm making a register (e.g. a school one) program in python using tkinter and i'm trying to add a new person to the register every time the person clicks submit but all that is happening is that it is overwriting the previous name meaning that the file that it is being saved to only have one name.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Some clarity: register_info and listees_info are the name of the register and the name of the latest person that is being saved to the file.

This is the part of my code:

```
def create_register():
    register_info = registername.get()
    listees_info = listees.get()
    list_of_registers=os.listdir()
    if register_info in list_of_registers:
        file=open(register_info,"w")
        file.close()
        Label(create, text = "Register Created", fg = "green" ,font = ("calibri", 8)).pack()
    with open(register_info,"a") as file_info:
        file_info.write(register_info+"\n")
        file_info.write(listees_info+"\n")
        file_info.close()
```

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on Tkinter but can you mention the file extension?

Comment: The append is fine, you probably delete the content of the file in the line `file=open(register_info,"w")`. Moreover, if you use the context manager `with open(...) as f:` you don't need to close the file at the end, that's the context manager job :)

Comment: The condition for creating the file should be *not in*, not *in*.

Comment: To add to jasonharper's comment, also note that you don't need to first open the file in write mode to create it - opening it in append mode will do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `w` mode you pass to `open` (in your line that reads `file=open(register_info,"w")`) tells python you want to open the file for writing. By design, this gets rid of anything else in the file and places the cursor at the beginning. It sounds like you want to open the file and append information to the end, without overwriting anything.

To do this, you should use the `a` mode for *append*. This opens the file for writing and places the cursor at the end of the file.

So, you need to say `open(register_info, "a")`.

I also suggest switching to a context manager which ensures the file is closed if any unexpected behavior happens. You would do this like:

```py
with open(register_info, "a") as file:
    # Any code that needs to use "file" here
```

More information about file opening modes (taken from another answer of mine):

> **`r`**: Opens the file in read-only mode. Starts reading from the beginning of the file and is the default mode for the open() function.
>
> **`rb`**: Opens the file as read-only in binary format. Places the cursor at the start of the file.
>
> **`r+`**: Opens a file for reading and writing. Places the cursor at the beginning of the file.
>
> **`w`**: Opens in write-only mode. Places the cursor at the beginning of the file. This will overwrite any existing file with the same name. It will create a new file if one with the same name doesn't exist.
>
> **`wb`**: Same behavior as `w`, except the file is opened in binary mode.
>
> **`w+`**: Opens a file for writing and reading. Replaces all content and creates the file if it doesn't exist. This mode is used when you need to write to an empty-file and potentially read from it later in your code (before closing).
>
> **`wb+`**: Same behavior as `w+` except the file is in binary mode.
>
> **`a`**: Opens a file for appending new information to it. The cursor is placed at the end of the file. A new file is created if one with the same name doesn't exist.
>
> **`ab`**: Same behavior as `a` except the file is in binary mode.
>
> **`a+`**: Opens a file for both appending and reading. The cursor is placed at the beginning of the file.
>
> **`ab+`**: Same as `a+` except the file is in binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

you should fix this part:

```py
    if register_info in list_of_registers:
        file=open(register_info,"w")
        file.close()
```

When you open this file in `w` mode, you're essentially resetting it.